# how to print the line if the match found

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl. I want to search a file for a word and nee to print the line if the match found

for example

`load-dump -dontstart ~/Setup/testing/dump_new.21260C_emudump.gz`

`set-io-configuration external`

`set-ap-info 6 0.0.0.0`

`create-io-device TW-0`

`create-io-device TW-1`

I want to search for **"load-dump"** and I want to print whole line when it found.

thanks in advance
murali

Answer (score 1):

[`Open`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm) the file and use [`gets`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/gets.htm) to [`read`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/read.htm) it line by line. [`For`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/for.htm) each line, test for the specified condition with [`regexp`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm) or [`string match`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm) and [`if`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/if.htm) true print the line using [`puts`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/puts.htm). Finally [`close`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/close.htm) the opened file.

Comment: Perhaps you meant “[`split`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/split.htm) the data into lines, and then [`foreach`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/foreach.htm) line…”?